# Path into PS1 prompt is broken (\n) on different lines when it is too long

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, iterm

I am using iTerm2 on MacOS Catalina . Here is my `PS1` into `~/.bashrc` , using a function `ps1` :

```
function ps1 {
        # PROMPT SECTION
        BLUE='\[\033[0;34m\]'
        LIGHT_CYAN='\[\033[1;36m\]'
        DEFAULT='\[\033[0m\]'
        PURPLE='\[\033[0;35m\]'
        LIGHT_PURPLE='\[\033[1;35m\]'
        LIGHT_GREEN='\[\033[0;32m\]'
        PINK='\[\033\[0;31m\]'


        # \! - History number of last command
        # $? - Exit value of last command
        # \t - Exit time of last command
        # \w - Current directory (relative)

PS1="$PURPLE|$DEFAULT$LIGHT_GREEN\u@$DEFAULT$LIGHT_CYAN\h$DEFAULT$PURPLE|$DEFAULT\t$PURPLE|$DEFAULT$LIGHT_PURPLE\w$DEFAULT$PURPLE|$DEFAULT "
}

ps1
```

The issue happens when I have long path, it seeems to  be broken on second or third line like this :

[image]

I tried to increase the number of columns (to 1000) into `iTerm2 -> Preferences` but it doesn't seem to fix this issue.

I can't see where the error comes from.

Anyone could see what's wrong ? Regards

```
  fab@astro|13:12:32|~/Phd_2019_2020/Travail_2_faire_varier_Omega_DE_sur_CAMB_et_regarder_si_les_P_k_changent_21_Octobre_2019/Main_Directory_Work/TSAF_lvl_up_Derivatives_15_points_on_Cl_stabilite_Code_is_surel
y_VALIDATED_for_15_points_derivatives_AND_After_trying_to_solve_the_pathologic_zone_1e-5_TO_1e-2_13_Novembre_2019/Test_FAIRE_VARIER_TOUS_LES_PARAMETRES_AVEC_les_2_pas_2e-2_et_1e-1_AVEC_Takabird_SECONDE_TENTATIVE_AVEC_LA_VAR        IATION_de_wde_EN_FLAT_DANS_Camb_launcher_6_DECEMBRE_2019/CAMB_der_3_pts/fortran|
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen in Terminal?

Comment: @nohillside yes, same issue with Terminal but I don't want to use Terminal, iTerm2 is great.

Comment: If the problem occurs both in Terminal *and* in iTerm it's probably something the shell does, not the terminal application. I didn't count the characters but does the line break occur after 256 characters (probably including any escape sequences)?

Comment: Did some more tests: It's related to the coloring, without colors it works as expected. Also, it doesn't seem to depend on the width of the terminal window, the break always occurs in the third line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug related to the old version of bash included in macOS.

To overcome you can

- Switch to `zsh` (see [What are the practical differences between Bash and Zsh?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/361870/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-bash-and-zsh))
- Install a more recent version of `bash` via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and use this as your standard shell (see [How to use bash as default shell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224511/how-to-use-bash-as-default-shell))

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! updating bash version fixed it . Regards